# Cambio de valor de las propiedades de un objeto de acuerdo a un Map

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

tengo el siguiente array de objetos el cual necesito mapear los valores de sus propiedades a uno que sea apropiado para otro sistema, para eso, generé un diccionario con cada clave-valor.

Ejemplo del array:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
    "_id": 22,
    "uuid": "xxxxxxxx",
    "lugar_inscripcion": "mdhyh",
    "nombre_apellido": "Juan Perez",
    "tipo_up": "grupo_asociativo",
    "nombre_up_emprend_negocio": "ConstruiMas",
    "comienzo_activ_up": "2021-10-14"   
    },
    {
    "_id": 23,
    "uuid": "xxxxxx",
    "lugar_inscripcion": "domicilio_propio_o_up",
    "nombre_apellido": "Juan Carlos",
    "tipo_up": "emprendedor_individual",
    "nombre_up_emprend_negocio": "Almacen La Ponderosa",
    "comienzo_activ_up": "2022-03-23",
    "calle_up": "Nazca"   
    }    
    ]
}
```

¿Como itero sobre cada uno de los objetos y recupero el valor de cada propiedad para poder hacer el método .get del Map y cambiarle el valor al correspondiente?

Un ejemplo del mapa:

```
const mapLugar = new Map();
map.set('mdhyh', 'Ministerio');
map.set('grupo_asociativo', 'grupo_asoc');
map.set('emprendedor_individual', 'emp_ind');
```

La idea sería que después de la iteración, los valores cambien al que corresponda su equivalente en el map.

```
{
    "data": [
    {
    "_id": 22,
    "uuid": "xxxxxxxx",
    "lugar_inscripcion": "Ministerio",
    "nombre_apellido": "Juan Perez",
    "tipo_up": "grupo_asoc",
    "nombre_up_emprend_negocio": "ConstruiMas",
    "comienzo_activ_up": "2021-10-14"   
    },
    {
    "_id": 23,
    "uuid": "xxxxxx",
    "lugar_inscripcion": "domicilio_propio_o_up",
    "nombre_apellido": "Juan Carlos",
    "tipo_up": "emp_ind",
    "nombre_up_emprend_negocio": "Almacen La Ponderosa",
    "comienzo_activ_up": "2022-03-23",
    "calle_up": "Nazca"   
    }    
    ]
}
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de la salida que esperas?

Comment: Hola Mauricio! Ya fue modificada la pregunta. La intención es que por cada valor que hay en el Map, se modifique el coincidente en el array. 

De todas formas, estoy probando y creo que lo logré con un foreach:


json.data.forEach(e => {
element['lugar_inscripcion'] = mapa.get(element['lugar_inscripcion']);
element['tipo_up'] = mapa.get(element['tipo_up']);
})


Si llega a funcionar una vez terminado ya cierro la pregunta. Caso que conozcas alguna forma más eficiente, agradezco tus comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres hacer es convertir cada elemento de un  array en un `Map` y asignarle sus propiedades, lo puedes hacer así:

```js
const response = {
    "data": [
    {
    "_id": 22,
    "uuid": "xxxxxxxx",
    "lugar_inscripcion": "mdhyh",
    "nombre_apellido": "Juan Perez",
    "tipo_up": "grupo_asociativo",
    "nombre_up_emprend_negocio": "ConstruiMas",
    "comienzo_activ_up": "2021-10-14"   
    },
    {
    "_id": 23,
    "uuid": "xxxxxx",
    "lugar_inscripcion": "domicilio_propio_o_up",
    "nombre_apellido": "Juan Carlos",
    "tipo_up": "emprendedor_individual",
    "nombre_up_emprend_negocio": "Almacen La Ponderosa",
    "comienzo_activ_up": "2022-03-23",
    "calle_up": "Nazca"   
    }    
    ]
};

const mapArray = response.data.map(e => new Map(Object.entries(e)));

console.log("probamos que funciona obteniendo el valor de nombre_apellido del segundo Map:", mapArray[1].get("nombre_apellido"));
```

Haciendo uso de `Object.entries` obtienes los pares de llave->valor y se los pasas al `Map`

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue de la siguiente manera:

```
json.data.forEach(e => { 

element['lugar_inscripcion'] = mapa.get(element['lugar_inscripcion']);
element['tipo_up'] = mapa.get(element['tipo_up']);

 })
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).